# iPhone 4 disabled after several failed password attempts?

Tags: iphone

My friend has an iPhone 4. Yesterday it got disabled after several failed passcode attempts. When you press the turn on/off switch or the home screen button, the following message appears:

> iPhone disabled. Connect to iTunes.

The problem is that it was synced with a computer she doesn't own anymore. And she doesn't want to lose any of her data. I wonder if it could be recovered without any data loss.

Answer (score 1):

The only way if you don't have a backup (on pc/mac or iCloud) is to recover data with a third-party software before you attempt to restore with iTunes.
[This](http://www.wondershare.com/data-recovery-mac/mac-iphone-data-recovery.html) one is well reviewed (but not cheap).